# Is it possible to highlight wanted files in Package Explorer/Navigator?

Tags: java, eclipse

Is it possible to highlight wanted files in Package Explorer/Navigator?

And by that I mean that I want eclipse to highlight certain files, which I tell for it.

For example:
Project will need to highlight **settings.ini**, so it will highlight it with wanted background color etc.

Is this possible with just eclipse or is there an plugin for it?

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse doesn't provide that feature. You'll need a plugin or develop a plugin. Take a look at: [Highlighting a class file in the package explorer in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14696250/highlighting-a-class-file-in-the-package-explorer-in-eclipse?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can now select the wanted file, but doesn't know how to make them highlighted (changed background color, text in bold etc.). Will need to examine more.